# WordPress Changed Hostname & Can't Access Admin

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to recover a WordPress site where the hostname changed (unintentionally or maliciously). Because of that I can't even access the admin panel. Is there anywhere in the DB or code that the hostname can be updated? Here is what I'm seeing:

[image]

Many thanks. Kate.

Comment: https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL did you even do any research before asking

Answer (score 1):

Some of the links are fine, as those are likely stored in the database as content.

Let's do some checks first to see if something changed that you can quickly edit yourself:

**Step 1**

Open the `wp-config.php` file.  Do you see the constants 'WP_SITEURL' and 'WP_HOME' being defined?  It would look like this:

```
define('WP_HOME','http://something.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://something.com');
```

If they are in there, make sure the URL is set to your website's domain address, as @Eravald indicated above.

If they are not in there, go ahead and add them per @Eravald's instructions:

```
define('WP_HOME','http://www.corecomplete.ca/');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://www.corecomplete.ca/');
```

**Step 2**

Let's check the settings in the database.  Open up phpMyAdmin and then the options table, which would be `wp_options` if you used the `wp_` as the database prefix.

The first two records are the `siteurl` and `home`.  Make sure those are set to `http://www.corecomplete.ca/`.

If no, do this:

1. Backup your database
2. Double click on the `option_value` column for the entry you want to
   change.  Then change it to the right domain URL.  Be Careful! You
   are changing your database.

Did it fix the problem?  If no, go to the next step.

**Step 3**

Contact your hosting provider. Let them do some checks.  It looks like a staging server IP address being applied to it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it will work but you can try to get into the database and then find the `wp_options` table and there you can change the value of `siteurl` and `home` or in `wp_site` the `domain` and `path`.

Answer (score 0):

Edit `wp-config.php` and add:

```
define('WP_HOME','http://www.corecomplete.ca');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://www.corecomplete.ca');
```